# Trouble with a CASE statement in a sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have just started using stored procedures in sql server and have been getting on reasonably well, but I have now come across a problem I can't understand. I have searched for an answer, but to be honest I am not sure I am asking the right question.

My sp is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [FindName]
    @Square nvarchar(100) = null,
    @Location nvarchar(100) = null,
    @Name nvarchar(100) = null,
    @NormalizedName nvarchar(100) = null,
    @SharedLand int = 0,
    @FieldNumber int = 0,
    @Description nvarchar(255) = null,
    @Dwelling nvarchar(100) = null
AS

BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM [Holdings]
    WHERE 
        ([Square] LIKE @Square OR @Square IS NULL)
        AND ([Location] = @Location OR @Location IS NULL)
        AND ([Name] LIKE @Name OR @Name IS NULL)
        AND ([NormalizedName] LIKE @NormalizedName OR @NormalizedName IS NULL)
        AND ([SharedLand] = @SharedLand OR @SharedLand = 0)
        AND ([FieldNumber] = @FieldNumber OR @FieldNumber = 0)
        AND ([Description] LIKE @Description OR @Description IS NULL)
        AND ([Dwelling] LIKE @Dwelling OR @Dwelling IS NULL)
        ORDER BY
            CASE WHEN (@NormalizedName IS NOT NULL) THEN [NormalizedName]
            ELSE [No]
        END
END
```

It all works fine with all EXECs using any or all parameters without the CASE but with a CASE statement, the following work:

```
EXEC FindName @Square = '%D%'
EXEC FindName @SharedLand = 1
```

But when I try:

```
EXEC dbo.cafgFindName @NormalizedName = '%Thomas%'
```

I get the error:
*Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Thomas' to data type int.*

What I can't understand is where is the conversion taking place, if indeed that is the problem.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because a CASE Statement must resolve to a single type. In this case (no pun intended :) you are considering an nvarchar OR an int (I presume [No] is an int).

See here for more details:
[Order by and Different Types in a CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214613/order-by-and-different-types-in-a-case)

Comment: Great. That put me in the right direction and I solved the problem. I found the quickest way to get what I was looking for was to do the following, and it worked.

    ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @NormalizedName IS NOT NULL THEN [NormalizedName] END,
    CASE WHEN (@NormalizedName IS NULL) THEN [No] END

Thanks

Comment: Yes, thanks Stephen Byrne. I also discovered that the way to sort by more than one field was to put two case statements, e.g.
`CASE WHEN @Dwelling IS NOT NULL THEN [Dwelling] END,   CASE WHEN @Dwelling IS NOT NULL THEN [FieldNumber] END`