# Use case statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I want to change the value in a result using a `case` statement, but it seems to ignore this. Very simple, if the value in the table is `1` then must change to `True`, if the value is `0` then must change to `false`. Here is what I did:

```
CASE pbc.bShownUp
    WHEN 0 THEN 'False'
    ELSE pbc.bShownUp 
END  
AND
CASE ch.bShownUp
    WHEN 1 THEN 'True'
    ELSE ch.bShownUp 
END
```

No matter what I do, the result is still 0 or 1.

Please help.

Comment: which DBMS are you using? and what do you mean by `result is still 0 or 1` - do you mean it shows 0 and 1 instead of True and False?

Comment: please give more context: what database? where is this CASE located? In the SELECT clause?

Comment: What is your DBMS? Is it MS SQL Server or something else? And what is data type of `pbc.bShownUp`?

Comment: Using MS SQL  in a select statement

Comment: yes, the result shows as 0 or 1 instead of true or false

Comment: Case expression, not case statement...

Comment: You say SELECT, but in select-list or in on/where-clause?

Comment: Please show a more complete query, I don't understand what the `AND` is doing there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're using a `CASE` Expression, the return type of the data has to be the same for all `WHEN` parts or more simply put, `CASE` must resolve to a single type.

More reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214613/order-by-and-different-types-in-a-case) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305925/trouble-with-a-case-statement-in-a-sql-server-stored-procedure/15306015#15306015)

From a Type point of view, at the moment your code says

```
CASE BIT
   WHEN 1 then NVARCHAR
   ELSE BIT
```

And that won't work.

So you have to do something like this

```
CASE ch.bShownUp
   WHEN 1 then 'TRUE'
   ELSE 'FALSE'
```

Comment: Case expression. (Case statement doesn't have any result value.)

Answer (score 2):

If `bShownUp` is numeric column, you are producing mixed result - sometimes 0/1, sometimes 'False'/'True' e.g. string. I suppose `bShownUp` is of type VARCHAR and you have to change `WHEN 0` to `WHEN '0'`.

Answer (score 2):

If your bShownUp is `VARCHAR` then your query should look like

```
CASE pbc.bShownUp
     WHEN '0' THEN 'False'
     ELSE pbc.bShownUp
END

AND

CASE ch.bShownUp
     WHEN '1' THEN 'True'
     ELSE ch.bShownUp
END
```

OR

Try something like below,

```
CASE pbc.bShownUp
         WHEN 0 THEN 'False'
         ELSE CAST(pbc.bShownUp  AS VARCHAR(10))
    END

    AND

    CASE ch.bShownUp
         WHEN 1 THEN 'True'
         ELSE CAST(ch.bShownUp  AS VARCHAR(10))
    END
```

Comment: the datatype of bShownUp is bit.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will do:

```
case ch.bShownUp
    when 1 then 'True'
    else 'False'
end
```