# How to parameterize order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple SQL script, and I want to parameterize the sort by:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetLog
    @SortDirection NVARCHAR(4),
    @SortBy NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Id 
    FROM dbo.TestLog
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 'asc' 
            THEN
                CASE
                    WHEN @SortBy = 'Id' THEN Id -- Id is an INT
                    WHEN @SortBy = 'IsDeleted' THEN Deleted -- Deleted is a BIT
                    WHEN @SortBy = 'Description' THEN Description -- Description is a NVARCHAR
                END
        END ASC,
        CASE 
            WHEN @SortDirection = 'desc' 
                THEN
                    CASE
                        WHEN @SortBy = 'Id' THEN Id -- Id is an INT
                        WHEN @SortBy = 'IsDeleted' THEN Deleted --  Deleted is a BIT
                        WHEN @SortBy = 'Description' THEN Description -- Description is a NVARCHAR
                    END
        END DESC
```

If `@SortBy = 'Id'`, everything works fine. However, if `@SortBy` is anything else, then an exception will be thrown:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12A' to data type bit

Is there anyway to fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: See also this article https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/conditional-order-by

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For optimal performance use dynamic SQL.  The CASE in ORDER BY will prevent using an index. eg

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.GetLog
@SortDirection NVARCHAR(4),
@SortBy NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat(N'
    Select Id from dbo.TestLog
    Order BY ', quotename(@SortBy), ' ', CASE When @SortDirection = 'desc' THEN 'desc' else 'asc' end)
    
    --print ( @sql )
    exec sp_executesql @sql
END
go
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggested solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to case your first case condition to SQL_VARIANT, and every after it will works accordingly. All thanks to [Martin Smith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214613/order-by-and-different-types-in-a-case).

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.GetLog
@SortDirection NVARCHAR(4),
@SortBy NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
Select Id from dbo.TestLog
Order BY
    CASE When @SortDirection = 'asc' THEN
        CASE
            WHEN @SortBy = 'Id' THEN CAST(Id AS SQL_VARIANT)
            WHEN @SortBy = 'IsDeleted' THEN Deleted
            WHEN @SortBy = 'Description' THEN Description
       END
    END ASC,
    CASE When @SortDirection = 'desc' THEN
        CASE
            WHEN @SortBy = 'Id' THEN CAST(Id AS SQL_VARIANT)
            WHEN @SortBy = 'IsDeleted' THEN Deleted
            WHEN @SortBy = 'Description' THEN Description
       END
    END DESC
```

Comment: That's going to be dog slow. Another alternative, slightly faster but still slow, is `ORDER BY CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 'asc' AND @SortBy = 'Id' THEN Id END ASC, CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 'desc' AND @SortBy = 'Id' THEN Id END DESC, ...` The fastest solution is to use dynamic SQL, just be careful to pass through parameters where possible